# Installing Chef [ Work Station, Chef Server, Node ]

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to configure chef workstation, server, and node.

I have questions on chef.

1. Chef server only can be Linux machine?
2. Can chef node be on any machine?
3. Can chef workstation be on any machine?

Am I right?

Comment: Hi @arvind-agrahari, welcome to SO or sort of ... Before you ask any questions here, all the members of that site expect you to have done a modicum of diligence. For your first question, go on google and type `Chef server only can be Linux machine?` https://learn.chef.io/install-and-manage-your-own-chef-server/linux/install-chef-server/install-chef-server-using-your-hardware/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you should not ask multiple questions in one posting, but all of them can be pretty much covered with: **Have a look at the [Chef download page](https://downloads.chef.io)!**

1. Chef Server is currently available for Debian and RHEL
2. Chef Client is available for many platforms, including Windows, AIX, MacOS and many more.
3. Chef Workstation (aka. ChefDK) is supported on Linux, MacOS and Windows.

> Am I right?

If "any" means "other than Linux", then you are kind of "right".

Answer (score 0):

chef servers can be on premise or hosted on chef side. it should be good if yor are using a RHEL or Debian.
Yes chef node can be any os type.
chefDK is generally supported for windows/ linux